# How do I record an audio track of unlimited length and save it to a file?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

How do I record an unlimited length audio track and save it to a PySide/PyQt file?

I need to record an unlimited length audio track in PySide. In future, recording will stop by pressing the button. I tried running the code from the official documentation [QMediaRecorder.](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtMultimedia/QMediaRecorder.html#PySide6.QtMultimedia.PySide6.QtMultimedia.QMediaRecorder.Quality)

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QDir
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaCaptureSession, QAudioInput, QMediaRecorder, QMediaFormat

session = QMediaCaptureSession()
audioInput = QAudioInput()
session.setAudioInput(audioInput)
recorder = QMediaRecorder()
session.setRecorder(recorder)
recorder.setMediaFormat(QMediaFormat.MP3)
recorder.setQuality(QMediaRecorder.HighQuality)
file_location = QUrl(QDir.currentPath() + '/test.mp3')
recorder.setOutputLocation(file_location)
recorder.record()
```

The program runs for about 2-3 seconds, after which it terminates with code 0. The file does not appear in the current directory. I was trying to run this on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run your script in a Qt eventloop:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import QDir, QUrl 
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import (
    QMediaCaptureSession,
    QAudioInput,
    QMediaRecorder,
    QMediaFormat,
)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    session = QMediaCaptureSession()
    audioInput = QAudioInput()
    session.setAudioInput(audioInput)
    recorder = QMediaRecorder()
    session.setRecorder(recorder)
    recorder.setMediaFormat(QMediaFormat.MP3)
    recorder.setQuality(QMediaRecorder.HighQuality)
    filename = Path(QDir.currentPath()) / "test.mp3"
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.fspath(filename))
    recorder.setOutputLocation(url)
    recorder.record()

    button = QPushButton("Stop")
    button.show()
    button.clicked.connect(recorder.stop)

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```